# Why Send Transaction is Error 'exceeds block gas limit'?

Tags: web3js, sendtransaction

Why can't I send Ethereum with a code like this :

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://provider')
const web3 = new Web3(provider)

const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('privkey is here')
let coinbase = account.address
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account)
web3.eth.defaultAccount = coinbase

web3.eth.sendTransaction({ from: coinbase, gas: 200000000, to: 'address send', value: (1 * (10 * 18)) }).then((receipt) => { console.log(receipt); }).catch((error) => { console.error(error); });
```

At show log like this :

> Error: Returned error: exceeds block gas limit

Answer (score 1):

The gas limit for a block is around 8 million, but you tried to send a transaction with a gas limit of 200 million gas.

Comment: oh ok thanks for your response, I will try it.